# Treasury Basis Trade - Real life example?

Tags: trading, treasuries

There have been some talks regarding the potential threat arising from Hedgefunds w.r.t. to their leveraged Treasury Basis Trade positions.
Besides some basics, I never fully grasped the mechanics of such a trade with all its nuances (margin calls, repo leverage etc.)
Could someone provide an example involving all those steps ?

Thanks

Comment: Please, share any research paper or the Internet page even the contents are sketchy.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really have a paper but..the issues can be multidimensional. Some are:

(1) Funding squeeze when repo rates explode (due to Bank balance sheet capacity, or other reasons). This can trigger massive basis unwinds.

(2) Rush to safe liquid assets and convenience which can push futures through cash even in a positively sloping yc environment, causing huge mark to market pain and therefore unwinds again.

(3) The trade is also cash intensive, since you clear futures at an exchange and finance repo with dealers. When vol picks up, margin requirements increase causing the gross up to become larger. Again, forcing big unwinds.